# download speed issues on mobile site (responsive)

Tags: wordpress, download

This question might be too vague for this forum, and if so I'll remove it.

Here's my issue: website takes up to 12 seconds to download on iPhone 5.

I have this site http://www.insidemarketblog.com

It loads fine on a computer and the site performs well on Pingdom speed test.

It's a wordpress site running DIYTHEMES 2 and Pearsonified skin.  I had a bunch of plug-ins (including W3 Total Cache), but removed ALL of them.  When I had W3 running, I had pingdom results in the mid-90's.

Regardless of what I do, the first page takes at least 10 seconds to download (and as you can see, the first page is one image and a little text).

Has anyone dealt with a similar issue?  (downloads fast on computer but like crap on mobile device?).

ps. Using GoDaddy, which I use for other sites and none of those site have this issue.

Am I overlooking something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: by me, no problem on mobile too

Comment: Thank u. So it downloaded in a reasonable time (under 3 seconds?). My results are so inconsistent.

Comment: I've tried on 5S and Sony Experia Z1 from European ip's. Below 3s.